# How do you remove Minwax stainable wood filler?

Tags: hardwood-floor

Recently my husband and I (who both have no idea what we are doing obviously) just got done redoing our wood floors throughout our entire house. Everything turned out great excpet for the few areas that I applied minwax stainable wood filler.  Well it's NOT stainable and I learned the hard way.  Our floors are a dark walnut color and the filler is almost white or light cream.  It looks horrible and the filler is cracking in spots.  It's in a high traffic area. The floor also has been gone over with poly.

How can I just remove the wood filler without damaging our floor?

Answer (score 1):

There is really only one way to rid yourselves of the "white" fill spots. You will need to carefully dig out a small amount of the filler so only dark wood is showing around the edges. You don't need to remove all the filler from the original hole. Buy a pre-colored filler crayon, Minwax and others make them. Match the color of the filler stick to your floor color. Sand a small area around your repair with fine sandpaper, an inch or two is plenty.  Fill the indent with the matching colored filler, smooth it well and put a couple of coats of urethane over the repair, feathering the urethane into the existing urethane finish. A foam brush would be good for this purpose.  Good luck.

Comment: I've found that using a nice, sturdy nail (not your finger nail, obviously, an actual nail) works great for scrapping things that were used to fill in holes and cracks.